# Distribution of $\frac{\overline X - \overline Y - (\mu_1 -\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac1{m+n-2} [(m-1)*s_1^2+(n-1)*s_2^2](\frac1{m}+\frac1{n})}}$

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I need to prove the following r.v has $t_{m+n-2}$ distribution 
$$\frac{\overline X - \overline Y - (\mu_1 -\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac1{m+n-2} [(m-1)*s_1^2+(n-1)*s_2^2](\frac1{m}+\frac1{n})}}$$
where $\overline X$ and $s_1^2$ are the mean sample and the quasivariance  of a s.r.s from a population $N(\mu_1,\sigma)$ and $\overline Y$ and $s_2^2$ are the  mean sample and the quasivariance of a s.r.s from a population $N(\mu_2,\sigma)$ ( the samples are independent).

It's easy to see most of it. I can prove the numerator divided by $\sigma$ has distribution $N(0,1)$ and the denominator divided by $\sigma$ has distribution $\chi^2_{m+n-2}$. However, I need to prove numerator and denominator are independent, and I don't know how to. Of course, $\overline X, \overline Y, s_1^2, s_2^2$ are pairwise independent but that doesn't guarantee anything , does it?

Comment: This is Fisher's t statistic. The fact that the samples are independent guarantees the independence of your numerator and denominator.

Comment: how can I prove it ?

Comment: At some point you need to use $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ for a random sample of size $n$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma).$ Then use 2 samples to show that the denominator is related the square root of a $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = m+n-2)$ random variable. // Stochastic independence of $\bar X$ and $S_x^2$ for a random sample from normal dist'n can be proved using an orthogonal linear transformation or by MGFs.

Comment: I already did that, BruceET. I just need to prove numerator and denominator are independent

Answer (score 1):

We end up with  some $$U=\frac{\overline X-\overline Y-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}}}\sim N(0,1)$$

And some $$V=\frac{(m+n-2)s^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{m+n-2}$$

, where we have the pooled variance $$s^2=\frac{(m-1)s_1^2+(n-1)s_2^2}{m+n-2}$$

Now $U$ is a function of $\overline X$ and $\overline Y$, and $V$ is a function of $s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$. Moreover, $(\overline X,\overline Y)$ is independent of $(s_1^2,s_2^2)$ (this can be verified using MGFs since in fact $\overline X,\overline Y,s_1^2$ and $s_2^2$ are all mutually independent of each other). Since (measurable) functions of independent random variables/vectors are also independent of each other, it follows that $U$ and $V$ are independent.

The required statistic is of course $T=\frac{U}{\sqrt{V/(m+n-2)}}$.

Comment: how do you prove ($\overline X, \overline Y$) is independent of ($s_1^2,s_2^2$)??? That can't be deduced from pairwise independence only. Maybe it's easy, but I need you to do it, I can't see it

Comment: how do you know they are mutually independent?

Comment: A rigorous (and lengthy) proof would be using change of variables to derive the pdf of $(\overline X,\overline Y,s_1^2,s_2^2)$. That's why I said it can be verified using moment generating functions.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to verify it.