# Prove $\sqrt{ \frac{(n+m-2)mn}{(n+m)(nS^2+mT^2)} }(\overline{X}-\overline{Y})$ follows t-distribution with degree of freedom of $(n+m-2)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$n$ and $m$ are integers greater than 2, $\sigma^2>0$ are real number.

A math exam and an English exam were held and there were n and m participants for each. The score of each exam follows the normal distribution with the same mean and $\mu$ the same variance $\sigma^2$.

Scores of the math exam are $X_1,...,X_n$ and of the English exam are $Y_1,...,Y_m$.

$\overline{ X }=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

$\overline{ Y }=\frac{1}{m}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m Y_i$

$S^2 = \frac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^2$

$T^2 = \frac{1}{m}\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n(Y_i-\overline{Y})^2$

Then, how can we prove that
$$\sqrt{ \frac{(n+m-2)mn}{(n+m)(nS^2+mT^2)} }(\overline{X}-\overline{Y})$$
follows t-distribution with degree of freedom of $(n+m-2)$?

Comment: Some of your recent questions have notably no personal input whatsoever, like this one. You might want to change that to generate better response.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3124090/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you for the advice. I can't understand what you mean by "personal input" simply because I'm not good at English. What should I change concretely?

Comment: I mean add your work/thoughts since these look like homework questions without any additional context.